# Смена цвета фона элемента CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, css-animation

У меня есть строка меню, которая изначально прозрачная, но если пользователь начинает листать сайт, то она меняет цвет. Меняю цвет я с помощью удаления и добавления класса с прописанным цветом (это важно и этого я изменить не могу)
Но цвет меняется резко. Можно ли сделать плавный переход от прозрачного цвета фона к цвету фона прописанному классу, который я добавляю элементу. Возможно, можно как-то "плавно добавлять класс" через JS?

Код JS

```
var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
windowTop > 75 ? $('#mainhead').addClass('navShadow') : $('#mainhead').removeClass('navShadow');
```

Код CSS

```
nav {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav.navShadow {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #fff);
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[Пишут](https://keithjgrant.com/posts/2017/07/transitioning-gradients/) , что градиенты не поддерживают `transition`, поэтому предлагается вариант, в котором у псевдоэлемента с градиентным фоном плавно меняется прозрачность:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#mainhead').toggleClass('navShadow', windowTop > 75);
  });
});
```

```css
#mainhead {
  height:20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f00;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#mainnav::after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navShadow #mainnav::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainhead">
    <div id="mainnav">NAV</div>
</nav>
<p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p>
```

Comment: градиентный фон можно двигать, иногда этим можно обойтись

Comment: @br3t Сейчас сделал такой код. Он почему-то не показывает должного перехода. Добавил код в вопросе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я говорю о том, что я сделал такой код и он всё равно не работает

Comment: @Дмитрий ваша верстка не соответствует вашим стилям. Если вы даете `navShadow` элементу `nav`, то у вас не может быть такого селектора `.navShadow nav`

Comment: @br3t Тогда как мне адаптировать Ваш код под свою вёрстку?

Comment: Покажите реальный кусок кода, который вы потом сможете вставить на свою страницу